# Convert .py to executeble linux file

Tags: python, linux, exe

How i can convert .py file to executeble linux file. Like "py-auto-to-exe" , but for linux

I'm search in browse, but it's usefull. Can you help me wiht this problem

Answer (score 0):

Install pyinstaller from CLI:

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

Create a executable file.

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py    #myscript means your file name
```

You will get an **.exe** with the same python file name.

like after conversion, **myscript.py** will be **myscript.exe**

If you want to change the name of the executable, use the **"--name"**

```
pyinstaller --onefile --name myexecutable myscript.py
```

--name means your any gien name for the .exe file if you want.